# How to sort data from XML as numeric in a dataGrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, sorting, wpfdatagrid

I have data in an XML file that I display in a dataGrid. (WPF, C#, VisualStudio 2013) One of the columns is numeric data. When I sort the column, it seems like it is translating it as alpha instead of numeric, though I have tried to specify that column as numeric...

XAML for dataGrid:

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[Record]}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" 
    Name="dataGridRank" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
           Header="Name" 
           Width="*"
           Binding="{Binding Element[Name].Value}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
           Header="Rank" 
           Width="*"
           Binding="{Binding Element[Rank].Value, StringFormat={}{0:N}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

XMLfile 'ranks.xml':

```
<Ranks xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <Record>
     <Name> A </Name>
     <Rank dt:dt="number"> 85 </Rank>
  </Record>
  <Record> 
    <Name> C </Name>
    <Rank dt:dt="number"> 105 </Rank>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Name> B </Name>
    <Rank dt:dt="number"> 95</Rank>
  </Record>
</Ranks>
```

C# code to load the xml file:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("Resources/ranks.xml").Root;
dataGridRanks.DataContext = xml;
```

What I want when I click on the column header to sort Rank is:

```
A 85

B 95

C 105

or 

C 105

B 95

A 85
```

And what I get:

```
C 105

A 85

B 95

or 

B 95

A 85

C 105
```

I have unsuccessfully tried both with and without the Stringformat or the dt:dt="number". I have tried Stringformat=N as well as StringFormat={}{0:N}.

What am I missing? It seems like this should be simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Element value attribute` is of type `string`. So column type is of string hence **default comparer of string is getting used here**.

And `StringFormat` won't work here since it won't change the type of binded property. It's just used for formatting string on GUI.

I would suggest to create anonymous type at runtime and bind it with that where your `Rank` property will of be of type `int` so that default comparer of int gets used.

**Code**:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("database.xml").Root;
dataGridRank.ItemsSource = xml.Elements("Record")
                            .Select(e => new { Name = e.Element("Name").Value,
                             Rank = Convert.ToInt32(e.Element("Rank").Value) });
```

**XAML:**

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" 
              Name="dataGridRank" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" 
                                Width="*"
                                Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rank" 
                                Width="*"
                                Binding="{Binding Rank}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```